# vsFTP, Apache Setup

Tags: apache2, vsftpd

I am new to Linux, but got my hand on an Ubuntu machine, I install `Apache2` and `vsftpd` after following some tutorial.

With Apache I got my Wordpress running, and ftp works fine too. Now I face a problem that I am not sure how to resolve. The Problem is when I try to activate the Permalink it doesn't activate as it cannot write to the `.htaccess` file. Similarly `wp-cache` plugin fails to create cache folder or write to the `.htaccess` file as needed.

so I opted to give `777` permission to my `wp-content` folder and as soon as I do that, it simply disables all my plugins saying `no file exists for plugin`.

Please suggest what should I do to fix this problem?

**EDIT**: I fix it by making www-data as user for vsftpd as well, so I got common user to run apache and vsftpd. this solve problem as now I don't have to create different groups or permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an Apache configuration issue. I happen to come across your issue before but yes it was quiet sometime. Please google more on WordPress on apache virtual host.

Also, bring back the permission to 755 until you can tweak the apache virtual host configuration.

Comment: currently I am reuploading complete plugin folder, so I can restore as it was during first upload. but what exactly I should google? Any suggestive keyword or phrase to look for?

Comment: I see you edited the question that you've solved the problem. That's cool.
Did you bring back permission to 755?

Comment: well I delete the folder and reupload it again to get default permission, which in my case were 754, however I still give 777 to wp-content though I think it is not required.